# php html email help?

Tags: newsletter, php

I'm using below code for php html email:

```
   $to      = $email; 
   $subject = 'ABC'; 
   $message = $content;
   $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
   $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
   $headers .= 'From: ABC <a@b.com>'."\r\n";
   mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); // Send our email
```

where

```
$content='<html>
    <head>
      <title>Thanks</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <b>Thanks for your email</b>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>'
```

Now the email received contains:

```
\r\n \r\n \r\n \r\n
\r\n
\r\n Thanks for your email\r\n
\r\n
\r\n
```

I have read several examples, I'm not doing anything wrong as far as format of header goes.
Can't identify problem, help?
Also, any help suggestions with implementation of e-newsletter would be helpful.

Comment: How does email client matter?

Comment: @Jonny Tom Yes, I will do that.

Comment: On second thoughts - is `$content` separated by `\r\n` or is it actual line returns (i.e. you hit Enter in the editor)? If it is `\r\n` then the `'` means that PHP will not parse escaped characters and you will need to use `"` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all no need to use `<Head>` tags in a mail formatted in HTML.

**Try this:**

```
$content = '<html><body>';
$content .='<div><b>Thanks for your email</b></div>';
$content .='</body></html>';
```

**Or this:**

```
$content = "
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
            <b>Thanks for your email</b>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>";
```

**One of them will do the trick.**

Comment: Which one of them worked ? And what do you mean form-filled ?
If the second one worked then nothing will interfere it.

Answer (score 0):

may be`\n\r` are interpreted as **Encoded HTML Text** .. so use html tags `<br>` and see for `\n`